# vimscript substitute last occurence (for opening corresponding test/spec-file)

Tags: javascript, testing, vim

i wrote a function, which opens a corresponding file for me.

I have a convention in my coding projects, that i save test-files in the same subfolderstructure like the original - to be tested - one.

for example:

```
project_dir/
|-->src/
|   |-->test.js
|-->test/
    |-->test_spec.js
```

so, if i am editing `test/test_spec.js` and call `OpenCorrespondingFile()` then src/test.js should be opened and vice-versa.

now i wrote the following function:

```
function! OpenCorrespondingFile()
  let l:filename=expand('%:t')
  let l:path=expand('%:p')
  if l:path =~ "/src/"
    let l:correspondingFilePath = substitute(l:path, "src/", "test/", "")
    let l:correspondingFilePath = substitute(l:correspondingFilePath, ".js", "_spec.js", "")
  elseif l:path =~ "/test/"
    let l:correspondingFilePath = substitute(l:path, "test/", "src/", "")
    let l:correspondingFilePath = substitute(l:correspondingFilePath, "_spec", "", "")
  endif
  execute "only"
  execute "split"
  execute "edit " . l:correspondingFilePath
  execute "wincmd j"
  execute "edit " . l:path
endfunction
:nnoremap <leader>oc :call OpenCorrespondingFile()<cr>
```

The Problem is, that if i have a path with test/ or src/ more than one time in it, the wrong part of the path is substituted.

So i need to know, how i can substitute the last occurrence of a pattern.

```
let l:correspondingFilePath = SUBSTITUTE_LAST_OCCURRENCE(l:path, "src/", "test/", "")
```

thx in advance!

## UPDATE: reafactored function

```
function! OpenCorrespondingFile()
  let filename=expand('%:t')
  let path=expand('%:p')
  if path =~ '/src/'
    let correspondingFilePath = substitute(path, '.*\zssrc/', 'test/', '')
    let correspondingFilePath = substitute(correspondingFilePath, '.js', '_spec.js', '')
  elseif path =~ '/test/'
    let correspondingFilePath = substitute(path, '.*\zstest/', 'src/', '')
    let correspondingFilePath = substitute(correspondingFilePath, '_spec', '', '')
  endif
  only
  execute "split " . correspondingFilePath
endfunction
:nnoremap <leader>oc :call OpenCorrespondingFile()<cr>
```

Comment: in short do you want to change string `blafooxfooyfoobar` into `blafooxfooy###bar` (last `foo` -> `###`)?

Comment: yes, Lucs comment solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `'.*\zssrc/'`.

- `.*` to consume everything,
- and `\zs` to mark the start of the match.

Comment: hmm, not finding src/ in the path, when i try your solution

Comment: ```let l:correspondingFilePath = substitute(l:path, ".*\zssrc/", "test/", "")```

Comment: Avoid double-quotes, they require to double backslashes. Use single-quotes instead when you are dealing with regexes. Unless you need to search for some special characters/sequences.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `edit` as `split` takes an argument. You don't need `execute` to execute `wincmd j` and `only`.

Comment: oh nice, my function is shorter now and looks nicer. how can i replace ```execute "split " . l:correspondingFilePath``` to ```split l:correspondingFilePath``` ?

Comment: There, you can't. At best you can have a dedicated function. For instance, [I have one](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffer.vim#L95) that splits-open unless the buffer is already opened, and that also works around the error `E36`.

Comment: If you want to simplify your function, you can also get rid of `l:`. Within functions, un-scoped variables are local-variables.